# How to access value of variable "i" from other class

Tags: java

I am learning java and I am facing issue while accessing a variable defined in a method of class A from class B. Here is my code:

```
public class A{
......
...... 
public int dummy(){
for(int i=1; i<=10; i++){
//here are some code
}
```

I want to access value of i in below class B. I was tried to achieve this but don't get any success.

```
public class B{
.....
.....
 A var1 = new A();
 int new = var1.i;
}
```

Comment: You can't, in this case. You should review a basic Java tutorial for the foundational concepts and syntax.

Comment: You can't access local variables outside the method they're defined in. And `new` is a reserved keyword.

Comment: Is there any way to access this variable i? What should i change in my code?

Comment: Is there a third class that these two are instantiated from?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to access `i` from outside `A`, you'll need to make it a public member, like this:

```
public class A{
    public int i;
    public int dummy(){
        for(i=1; i<=10; i++){
            // some code
        }
    }
}
```

There isn't much use for what you describe, though. Normally an iterator like the index `i` is declared local to the loop (not accessible outside the loop, let alone the function or class) because it has no meaning to anything outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this, the variable `i` declared in the `for` loop is only accessibile inside the `for` loop.

if you want to access the variable the way you are trying you must to declare it as a instance variable or static variable.

```
public class A{
public int j;
...... 
public int dummy(){
for(int i=1; i<=10; i++){
 j = i;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your current implementation, you cannot access `i` as it is declared locally in your for loop and not as a member variable or a static variable of class A.
You also cannot name a variable `new`, as `new` is a reserved word.

```
public class A {
    private int i = 1;
    public int getI() {
        return this.i;
    }
}

public class B {
    public void someMethod() {
       A var1 = new A();
       int var2 = var1.getI();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class A{

    public A(){

    }

    public int dummy(){

        int i;

        for(i=1; i<=10; i++){
            //here are some code
        }

        return i;
    }
}


public class B{

    public B(){
        A var1 = new A();
        int new = var1.dummy();
    }
}
```

That work?